# Unable to handle Confirm Navigation pop up in my automation

Tags: javascript, selenium, sahi

i am trying to automate a page using SAHI(basically uses the javascript programming language). When i try to navigate from one url to the other i am getting the confirm navigation popup and the browser is stuck till i  take any action. Now this popup is not getting removed using the automation and the automation is failing because of this. 
Has anyone faced same issue? How do i ask my Sahi script to accept or decline this popup.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: driver.switchto().alert(); 

 

alert.accept()

Comment: Are you sure it's a normal browser alert? Sahi should usually handle these. Have you had a look at the _expectConfirm() Api and such?

Comment: no it dosent work with either of them. The browser becomes inactive till u manually handlie this Confirm navigation popup.